# exception: FieldPath 'C6' doesn't start with $" in mongo Java

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am working on `Mongodb` by using `Java`. In that I am trying to select certain record under some conditions including `group by`. The code I have used is as follows.

```
DBObject wherequery = new BasciDBOBject();
wherequery.put("deviceID", C6);
wherequery.put("reqTime", new BasicDBObject(
    "$lt", sometime)
    .append("$gt", someothertime));
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project",
    wherequery);
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id",
    "$requestID");
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(project, group);
```

when I run this code, I am getting following error:

```
exception: FieldPath 'C6' doesn't start with $"
```

what this error means? It denotes `deviceID C6` that I have used. what I am missing or how am I wrong?

please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select documents that match specified condition, you should use `$match` operator for your first pipline stage, not `$project`.

Answer (score 1):

Add  your `wherequery` to `$match` and for `project` used different `DBObject` check code as below :

```
DBObject wherequery = new BasciDBOBject();
wherequery.put("deviceID",C6 );
wherequery.put("reqTime", new BasicDBObject(
    "$lt", sometime)
    .append("$gt", someothertime));
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match",
    wherequery);
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("_id",
    "$requestID");
DBObject group = new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields);
//for projecting data 
DBObject projectData = new BasciDBOBject();
projectData.put("deviceID", "$deviceID"); // projectData.put("deviceID", 1); this also work
projectData.put("reqTime", "$reqTime");
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project",
    projectData);
AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(match, group,project);
```

For more check this **[Mongo Java driver for aggregation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/quick-tour/)**

Comment: Thanks  for your reply with code , that's works with match and group itself.I think i don't  need to project data.Why do we project waht that's means is it for exclude the field from the document Is i should have to project that

Comment: @Vicky the project data was **optional**  if required then add other wise forgot it, After looking your code I think you need `project` that's why I added `project` in code. Other wise it an optional